# Level 1 headers in profile description appear cluttered

Tags: bug, design, user-profile

I recently updated my Stack Exchange profile to include a link to my newly created Area 51 proposal [Scientific Imagination](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75912/scientific-imagination?referrer=IPIEcsN2huMFuP7v0aO_3g2). I included a sample question from the proposal as a level 1 header. It looks good on my Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow profiles, but here it appears very cluttered.

[Stack Exchange profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/262588/krumia):

[image: Stack Exchange profile]

[Stack Overflow profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1461424/krumia):

[image: Stack Overflow profile]

[Programmers profile](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/139479/krumia):

[image]

Can we do a little tweak to site's CSS to make it a bit more appealing?